# When you disable button[type=submit], is it possible to trigger a submit event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

For instance by hitting <kbd>return</kbd> while in an input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. try the sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/tun8js68/

```
<form action="http://www.w3schools.com/html/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"  disabled>
</form>
```

You still can submit form with javascript.